# Angular service do not returning any data in a controller while doing http post

Tags: angularjs

Angular service do not returning any data in a controller while doing http post.

```
app.controller("letter_active", function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.artist = myService.getReplyType2();
});

app.service('myService', function ($http) {

    this.getReplyType2 = function () {
        $http.post('file/getReplyType', {})
        .success(function (data, status) {
            return data;
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            alert("Error has occured" + status);
        });
    }
});
```

Need help for me novice in angular

Comment: Please at least check your grammar and punctuation if you expect people to take time from their day to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For asynchronous calls you need to return promise

```
this.getReplyType2 = function() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({method: 'POST', url: 'file/getReplyType', data: {}})
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                defer.resolve(data);
                    })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                window.data = data;
            });

    return defer.promise;
}

app.controller("letter_active", function ($scope, myService) {
    myService.getReplyType2().then(function(data) {
        $scope.artist = data;    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical work with asynchronous services in Angular is that the service returns a Promise object, and in controller you use `then/success` methods of this promise to set scope data:

```
app.controller("letter_active", function ($scope, myService) {
    myService.getReplyType2().then(function(data) {
        $scope.artist = data;    
    });
});

app.service('myService', function ($http) {

    this.getReplyType2 = function () {
        return $http.post('file/getReplyType', {}).success(function (data, status) {
            return data;
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            alert("Error has occured" + status);
        });
    }
});
```

Note, that `getReplyType2` method now returns a result of `$http.post` call, which is a Promise object.

Comment: return data; << i guess you'd better delete this line

Comment: @user2601893 It should be `myService.getReplyType2().then`, I guess it's a typo.

Comment: thanks dfsk it is returning data fine... but another problem arises that it is not binding for ng-repeat or `ng-options="a.cmn_name for a in artist"`..

Comment: How do you call `getReplyType2`, when it's called?